# DateList coupled with String Operations

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, date-and-time

Through some webscraping, I have the following list:

```
dates={{"<h3>January 18, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>February 1, 2001</h3>"},
{"<h3>February 2, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>February 24, 2001</h3>"},
{"<h3>February 26, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>March 1, 2001</h3>"},
{"<h3>March 2, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>March 31, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>April
5, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>April 18, 2001</h3>"}, {"<h3>May 6, 2001</h3>"}};
```

I am trying to make this into a `DateList[]` list. I can make it human readable in the following fashion:

```
datelist = StringReplace[
  ToString[dates], "<" ~~ Except[">"] .. ~~ ">" -> ""]
```

> {{January 18, 2001}, {February 1, 2001}, {February 2, 2001}, \
>   {February 24, 2001}, {February 26, 2001}, {March 1, 2001}, {March 2, \
>   2001}, {March 31, 2001}, {April 5, 2001}, {April 18, 2001}, {May 6, \
>   2001}

This brings up a list of nice dates. The only problem is that they are now a string. The list operations that I have tried to use (Cases, Pick, etc.) all deal with the whole part of a list, rather than sub-sets of each part.

Is there a quick way to convert what I have in dates to a Mathematica-readable `DateList[]`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The format specification for `DateList` is pretty flexible.  Since we know that we have `<h3>` tags wrapped around things, we can just account for them:

```
DateList[{#, {"<h3>", "MonthName", "Day", ",", "Year", "</h3>"}}] & /@ Flatten[dates]

(*
==> {{2001, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0.},
     {2001, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 
     {2001, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
     {2001, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0.}}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

You only need a slight modification to your `StringReplace` to get rid of the HTML tags:

```
datestr = StringReplace[#, "<h3>" | "</h3>" :> ""] & /@ dates
(* {{"January 18, 2001"}, {"February 1, 2001"}, {"February 2, 2001"}, {"February 24, 2001"}, 
    {"February 26, 2001"}, {"March 1, 2001"}, {"March 2, 2001"}, {"March 31, 2001"}, 
    {"April 5, 2001"}, {"April 18, 2001"}, {"May 6, 2001"}} *)
```

This result can be interpreted as a valid date string and converted to a `DateList` as follows:

```
DateList[{#, {"MonthName", "Day", "Year"}}] & @@@ datestr
(* {{2001, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

First one has to clean the starting list and replace the "\n" character with a space (if, as suggested by R.M,  the extra `\n` came in from pasting the code then the `StringReplace` bit is not necessary).

```
DateList[{StringSplit[#, {"<h3>", "</h3>"}][[1]][[1]], {"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ", 
 "Year"}}] & /@ (StringReplace[#, {"\n" -> " "}] & /@ dates)
```

Comment: I thought that `\n` came in from his pasting the code here (_Mathematica_ adds a \ to indicate continuation, but I generally remove it as do many others). But if not, you're right. That should've certainly been considered if it indeed was in the OP's list.

Comment: @R.M I think you're actually right - added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[DateList /@ StringReplace[#, {"<h3>" -> "", "</h3>" -> ""}] & /@ dates, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

One can extend and modify your code a little to get this:

```
datelist = 
 DateList@StringReplace[ToString[#], 
     "<" ~~ Except[">"] .. ~~ ">" -> ""] & /@ Flatten[dates]

(*
==> {{2001, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 
  2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 26, 0, 0, 
  0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 31, 
  0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 
  5, 6, 0, 0, 0.}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(DateList@StringTrim[First@#, "<h3>" | "</h3>"]) & /@ dates
```

or

```
DateList /@ StringTake[First /@ dates, {5, -6}]
```

or

```
(DateList @@ StringCases[First@#, "<h3>" ~~ a__ ~~ "</h3>" :> a]) & /@ dates
```

or

```
StringCases[First /@ dates, "<h3>" ~~ a__ ~~ "</h3>" :> DateList[a]]
```

or

```
Sequence @@@ StringReplace[First /@ dates, "<h3>" ~~ a__ ~~ "</h3>" :> DateList[a]]
```

all give

```
(* {{2001, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 
{2001, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 
{2001, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
{2001, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a separate answer as it is not a modification of your original attempt. It uses `StringCases`, and manually constructs a valid `DateList`. Since `DateList` was added in v6, this should also work for older versions. Note that one can replace the `months` in my `With` block with a manual list of 12 names.

```
With[{months = System`DateStringDump`getCachedMonths@""},
    (StringCases[#, "<h3>" ~~ m : LetterCharacter .. ~~ " " ~~ d : DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
        ", " ~~ y : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "</h3>" :> 
        {ToExpression@y, Position[months, m][[1, 1]], ToExpression@d, 0, 0, 0}
        ] & /@ dates
    )~Flatten~2
]

(* {{2001, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 2, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {2001, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2001, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0.}} *)
```